# How to edit DateObjects?

Tags: date-and-time

I have problems with removing time and time zone information from a date object. I found the same question here already, but my starting position is slightly different.
My date objects are imported from excel and look like

```
DateObject[{2008, 7, 3}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> 2.], TimeZone -> 2.]
```

What I need is `DateObject[{2008, 7, 3}]`, but I have no idea how I could get rid of all the rest. Does anybody know?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both of your expression **evaluate** to a different form (run `InputForm` on either `DateObject[{2008, 7, 3}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> 2.], TimeZone -> 2.]` or `DateObject[{2008, 7, 3}]`), so it isn't clear what it is you want to do with your `DateObject`.  That being said, have a look at [`DayRound`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayRound.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
dos = { DateObject[{2008, 7, 3}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> 2.], TimeZone -> 2.] ,
  DateObject[{2008, 7, 4}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> 2.], TimeZone -> 2.] }
```

[image]

```
f1 = DateObject[#,"Day"]&;
f1 /@ dos
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use

```
f2 = # /. DateObject[d_, ___] :> DateObject[d, "Day"]&;

f2 /@ dos == f /@ dos
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

You many use [`CurrentDate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentDate.html) or [`DayRound`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayRound.html).

```
dt = Now
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
CurrentDate[dt, "Day"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DayRound[dt]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.